# How do I make gcloud work on opensuse 13.2 in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I spin up an instance with `opensuse 13.2 (x86_64 built on 2015-05-11)` in Google Cloud, ssh to the instance, try to run `gcloud` and get following error:

`evgeny@tea-2:~> gcloud

python: can't open file '/usr/bin/../lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/gcloud.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

How do I make it work?

Comment: Thanks for reporting. We will work with opensuse to resolve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a bug of some sort. Can try reinstalling it? Try running:

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

then log out and log back in

Answer (score 1):

You can pull gcloud directly from Google as shown in Answer #1 or you can use the packaged version from the openSUSE repositories.

After logging in via ssh:

```
~> sudo -i
# zypper ar -t rpm-md -n 'Cloud Tools Devel'   http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Cloud:/Tools/openSUSE_13.2/ cloud_tools_devel
# zypper install google-cloud-sdk-0.9.44-13.2.noarch
```

You will need to accept the build key for the new repository that was added.